# I can not get my JavaScript code to work in my HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a carousel and i can not get the JavaScript to work at all. I am really bad at JS and need help finding out why i cant get it to work. This isnt the full final product, right now im just trying to get it to scroll when i click the button that's it. Since i do not know JS i was following a youtube tutorial and i followed it exact and still cant get it to move. i tried a few different ways even trying to put the JS code directly in the HTML and im at a loss.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img src="im3.JPG" id="lastclone">
            <img src="im1.JPG">
            <img src="im3.JPG">
            <img src="im1.JPG" id="fistclone">
        </div>


    </div>

    <button id="prevBtn" onclick="changestate()">prev</button>
    <button id="nextBtn" onclick="changestate()">next</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and for my JS

```
const carouselslide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselimage = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

//Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//counter
let counter = 1;
const size = carouselimage[0].clientwidth;

carouselslide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

//Button listiner
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    carouselslide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselslide.stle.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    carouselslide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselslide.stle.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});
```

Comment: Might be you have not referenced js path correctly check here how to put the relative path to JS: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/

Comment: You have started learning JS with slightly complex code, make sure you start with simple code of single task. Have you checked these variables `carouselslide` and `carouselimage` if not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You have two click listener.

one is :

```
<button id="prevBtn" onclick="changestate()">prev</button>
```

and other is :

```
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    carouselslide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselslide.stle.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});
```

While clicking, it tries to call **changestate** method which does not exist.

Please remove one of them and keep one.

Comment: i just removed the one from the HTML file and its still not working for me

Comment: the change state one is the one i removed

Comment: @dachil1pil1 there is no other reason for not working unless you do not refer js file properly. Your app.js and your html file both are on same folder?

Comment: yes that's why im very confused. i have triple checks all the little things like that and spelling all of it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the script tag right after the `</body>` tag and seeing if that works?

Comment: `<script>` is not a valid child of `<html>`

Comment: @Pablo not sure what you're referring to, but you're able to add the javascript script tag in html.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html

Comment: I stand corrected. However, I would not recommend such a practice.